# How to return a string that is between dot and before parentheses

Tags: java

I have the following text `ArtClass_Private_Method.boo(I)Z`. I would like to return only the string after the dot and before parentheses. In this case, the word `boo` should only be returned. For that, I tried the following:

```
String x = "ArtClass_Private_Method.boo(I)Z";
String[] wo = x.split("\\.");
System.out.println(wo[1]);
```

But this only returns boo(I)Z and I don't know how to avoid `(I)Z`.

Can someone help me fixing that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `indexOf` to find the `.`:

```
int dotPos = x.indexOf('.');
```

Use `indexOf` to find the following `(`:

```
int parenPos = x.indexOf('(', dotPos);
```

Then take the substring between (adding 1 to `dotPos` so you start after it):

```
String between = x.substring(dotPos + 1, parenPos);
```

(This assumes the `.` and the `(` can be found. I'll leave you to handle the case when they're not).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex `(?<=\\.).+(?=\\()`

```
String x = "ArtClass_Private_Method.boo(I)Z";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.).+(?=\\()");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(x);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // boo
```